# Arabic text files searching and indexing

Tags: c#, database-design, full-text-search, arabic, full-text-indexing

I am working on a project of an electronic library (for Arabic books). A program that allows the user to import his books into the systems library and perform searching against his library. The system is delivered to the user with a basic library (set of books) that the  user ca update later.

To handle the searching problems, i thought for the system to have an initial table in the DB for the basic searching keywords. Every search keyword points to its locations in the books in the library.

The problem appears when in the user imports a new book into the library. There are two step.
The first search the keywords that are already into the system against the new book to find if any of them appear in the book and add there location into the system.
The second, which the main stumbling block, is to identify NEW search keywords in the new book.

The idea that i have, which i think is pretty bad and naive, is to break the new book into tokens and then search each token against all the book previously found in the library.

so to sum-up, if any help (tools, libraries or DB options) or idea to solve the second problem or another idea for the whole system, i appreciate. really tried reading and searching a lot of a solution, but in-vain.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

You want [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). You will need to use the Arabic Analyzer.

Comment: First thanks a lot for the response. Second i have some points that i don understand.
What i know about Lucene, correct me if i am wrong, is that Lucene is a library that will allow me to do text search through a given document or a file on a given search token.

about the Arabic Analyzer, i really didn't get what it is used for, through searching. what will be its use with Lucene.

also making a text search against ~6000 documents, wont it be an overload ?
Thanks again,

Comment: Lucene will build an _index_ of the documents. It's the index that is searched. Your search is not limited to a token, you can search for phrases and do other types of searches. The analyzer finds words to index. To get the best results for a language the analyzer needs to be designed for the language. For example, an analyzer designed for English wouldn't recognize different forms of an Arabic word as the same word. The link **guest** posted has an overview of how Lucene works.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-apache-lucenesearch/index.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.